# php mysql AND operator

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I get a error message saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'key='12345' AND id='98765' LIMIT 1' at line 1

My code is:

```
$key = '12345'; 
$id = '98765';  
include realpath('./inc/config.php');

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE key='{$key}' AND id='{$id}' LIMIT 1", $config) or die(mysql_error());
            $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Now can anyone tell me whats wrong in this?

Comment: I am not certain but are you sure you have used proper quotes for key (it appears to me as non-digit data)???

Comment: why are you putting braces with the variables ?

Comment: what are the datatypes for the fields key and id ???

Comment: Damn sorry guys key is a predefined function in mysql or something like that you know primary key and all so it gives and error i changed it from key to keys and it worked and its not necessary to put braces?? EDIT: No sorry anything except key even keys are not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`key` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to properly quote it with backticks if you want to use it as a field name.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `key`='{$key}' AND id='{$id}' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 You beat me to it by a few minutes. Oh, how I hate my net connection :P

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `key`='{$key}' AND id='{$id}' LIMIT 1
```

*key is a reserved word*

Comment: try running that query in ur mysql database directly and try by taking off ' ' too and run it

Answer (score -2):

Your key and id are obviously numeric. Although adding quotes wouldn't hurt, you definitely don't need them. You edon't need brackets in any query period.
Try this:

```
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE key=$key AND id=$id LIMIT 1", $config) or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

If that doesn't work just run this using PHPMyAdmin or whatever you use to run queries on your db.

```
         SELECT * FROM users WHERE key=12345 AND id=98765
```

I also don't see why you would need LIMIT clause. It wouldn't break anything but if your id is actually row id it should give you a unique record.